# Error while binding values to form field in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm getting the following error, while using ExtJs MVC,

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined**

I traced the above error which goes to the line where i bind values from model to view,

```
Ext.getCmp('myForm').loadRecord(myModel);
```

Some of my form fields are disabled, and i'm still binding them. Is this the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs, whenever my model contains irregular data ( especially while trying to bind this unavailable data to a dual list ). Say my dual list contains item values like (A,B,C ) and when i'm trying to bind D, then this error occurs.